# Jupyter lab: is it possible to display output only in a separate view

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I've been working with Jupyter notebooks quite a while but right now, I'm switching to Jupyter lab. I really like it, especially the possibility to create a new view for my outputs and hide the output from the main notebook. However, once you run the same cell again, the output in the main notebook is no longer hidden. Is there a possibility to rerun a cell by hiding its output in the main notebook and showing it only in the new view?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar this might partially solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, at the time of writing, `sidecar` doesn't work with Jupyter Lab 3 yet.

Comment: It works with JupyterLab 3.0 now.

Comment: JupyterLab 4.0 will include an option to display any variable in a separate view via the Debugger.